# find a pattern and print line based on finding the first pattern sed, awk grep

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a rather large file. What is common to all is the hostname to break each section  example :

```
HOSTNAME:host1
   data 1
     data here
   data 2 
      text here
   section 1
      text here
   part 4  
      data here
   comm = 2

HOSTNAME:host-2

   data 1
     data here
   data 2 
      text here
   section 1
      text here
   part 4  
      data here
   comm = 1
```

The above prints

As you see above, in between each section there are other sections broken down by key words or lines that have specific values

I like to use a oneliner to print host name for each section and  then print which ever lines I want to extract under each hostname section

Can you please help. I am using now grep -C 10 HOSTNAME | gerp -C pattern
but this assumes that there are 10 lines in each section. This is not an optimal way to do this; can someone show a better way. I also need to be able to print more than one line under each pattern that I find .  So if I find data1 and there are additional lines under it I like to grab and print them

So output of command would be like

```
grep -C 10 HOSTNAME | grep data 1  
grep -C 10 HOSTNAME | grep -A 2 data 1 

HOSTNAME:Host1

   data 1  

HOSTNAME:Hoss2

   data 1
```

Beside Grep I use this sed command to print my output

```
sed -r '/HOSTNAME|shared/!d' filename
```

The only problem with this sed command is that it only prints the lines that have patterns shared & HOSTNAME in them. I also need to specify the number of lines I like to print in my case under the line that matched patterns shared. So I like to print HOSTNAME and give the number of lines I like to print under second search pattern shared.

Thanks

Comment: Won't `grep -E 'HOSTNAME|data 1' file` work for you?

Comment: `I like to use a oneliner` - When did avoiding white space become a desirable quality in software???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed -n -e '/hostname/,+p' -e '/Duplex/,+p'
The simplest way to do it is to combine two sed commands ..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `sed` twoliner:

```
sed -n -r '/HOSTNAME/ { p }                                  
          /^\s+data 1/ {p }' hostnames.txt
```

It prints (`p`)

- when the line contains a HOSTNAME
- when the line starts with some whitespace (`\s+`) followed by your search criterion (`data 1`)
- non-mathing lines are not printed (due to the `sed` `-n` option)

Edit: Some remarks:

- this was tested with GNU sed 4.2.2 under linux
- you dont need the `-r` if your sed version does not support it, replace the second pattern to `/^.*data 1/`
- we can squash everything in one line with `;`

Putting it all together, here is a revised version in one line, without the need for the extended regex ( i.e without `-r`):

```
sed -n '/HOSTNAME/ { p } ; /^.*data 1/ {p }' hostnames.txt
```

Comment: hi I am getting an error  sed -n -r '/HOSTNAME/ { p } /^\s+driver/ {p }' ads.env   << sed: illegal option -- r

Comment: using it on same line

Comment: @theuniverseisflat Needs `;` to separate commands on the same line.

Comment: sed -n -r '/HOSTNAME/ { p };/^\s+driver/ {p }' ads.env does it matter if this is a soalris host?

Comment: I just ran it under linux adding the ; , but  it does not print the line that contains the second pattern, It only prints the ine containing the HOSTNAME

Comment: That's strange, `command1;command2` should work, and if both are `/condition/action` both conditions should be checked on each line, and the appropriate(s) action(s) executed. You could try using the `sed <other flags> -e 'command1' -e 'command2' [...]` syntax instead.

Comment: On a side note, braces are optional when there is only one command to execute, and flags can be aggregated. I would have written the answer as `sed -nr '/HOSTNAME/p;/^\s+data 1/p' hostnames.txt`.

Comment: no it only prints the host name - my second search pattern is shared

Comment: sed -nr '/HOSTNAME/p;/^\s+shared 1/p' ads.env

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v lines=2 '/HOSTNAME/{c=lines} NF&&c&&c--' file

HOSTNAME:host1
   data 1
HOSTNAME:host-2
   data 1
```

print `lines` number of lines including pattern match, skips empty lines.

If you want to specify secondary keyword instead number of lines

```
$ awk -v key='data 1' '/HOSTNAME/{h=1; print} h&&$0~key{print; h=0}' file

HOSTNAME:host1
   data 1
HOSTNAME:host-2
   data 1
```

Comment: Hi - this is not what I need. I need to specify the 2nd search pattern - not just to print 2 lines

Answer (score 0):

The OP requirements seem to be very unclear, but the following is consistent with one interpretation of what has been requested, and more importantly, the program has no special requirements, and the code can easily be modified to meet a variety of requirements.  In particular, both search patterns (the HOSTNAME pattern and the "data 1" pattern) can easily be parameterized.

The main idea is to print all lines in a specified subsection, or at least a certain number up to some limit.

If there is a limit on how many lines in a subsection should be printed, specify a value for limit, otherwise set it to 0.

```
awk -v limit=0 '
  /^HOSTNAME:/ { subheader=0; hostname=1; print; next}
  /^ *data 1/  { subheader=1; print; next }
  /^ *data /   { subheader=0; next }          
  subheader && (limit==0 || (subheader++ < limit)) { print }'
```

Given the lines provided in the question, the output would be:

```
HOSTNAME:host1
   data 1
HOSTNAME:host-2
   data 1
```

(Yes, I know the variable 'hostname' in the awk program is currently unused, but I included it to make it easy to add a test to satisfy certain obvious requirements regarding the preconditions for identifying a subheader.)